# Calibrate Sample: What kind of data do I need to address non-respondents?

Tags: weighted-sampling

I want to weigh my sample to include non-respondents in my estimations.
We have multiple factors which should be taken into account.
So it's not only about weighing after gender for example.

We have up to 5 factors. 
(Male, Age Class, Function in Company, etc.)

My understanding is, to calculate those weights, I would need information like these:

Eighter every individual with information about the factors, e.g. a table like:

`Individual A | Gender | Age-Class | Function`

or exact population information for every subgroup, e.g. a table like:

`Group A | Male, Age Class B, Function A | 2,3 %`

Our problem, we won't get this information. My question is, are there ways to compute multifactorial weights only from the general population information? From something like that:

`Gender: 54 % male, 46 %
Age Classes: 13 % A, 17 % B etc.
Functions: 2 % Function A, 18 % Function B, etc.`

Every hint or solution is highly appreciated thank you!
:)

Comment: When you say, you want to weight for non-respondents, do you actually mean people who were invited and supposed to have completed the survey, but didn't (i.e. non-response weights) or do you mean you want to weight your data to reflect population estimates (i.e. traditional sampling weights)?

Comment: no sorry you are right - I want to reflect the population estimates

Comment: Thanks that is indeed a good link but the technic wasn't part of my question because what I am interested in is what population information do I need. And it seems from the link that I need for every case the information. Or for every sub-group. So it seems it is not enough to have information as I posted as an example at the end of my question.

Comment: YES thanks that are actually good new. I also find thx to your keyword this article http://faculty.nps.edu/rdfricke/docs/rakingarticlev2.2.pdf. Thank you very much for your patience and answers. When you add your answer as "answer" than I am happy to accept it as the solution. Thank you, that's the outcome I hoped for :)

Comment: I went ahead and moved my comments into an answer since it seemed that this is what you were looking for.  I'll delete my comments after acceptance to clean up this post too.

Comment: Re: Function in Company. Seems obvious to me that the population is within a company. So contact HR and ask for a breakdown of employees for your factors.

Comment: It is for companies but we introduce new factors which are employees not grouped in. So this data doesn't exist. And I can tell you from long year experienced, how hard it is to even get the simplest information from companies. Even if they want to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need to do is called "raking." Raking or "sample-balancing" is a weighting method that allows you to weight up/down your sample data according to **marginal** "control totals" from a known population. You can find this method covered in many sampling texts, such as Sharon Lohr's [Sampling: Design and Analysis, 2d (p 344-5) book](https://books.google.com/books?id=aSXKXbyNlMQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Sharon%20Lohr&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3xem82uHiAhUmh-AKHUklAIIQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=Sharon%20Lohr&f=false) and a google search for "Raking Survey Data" yields several good tutorials such as this [one](https://datawookie.netlify.com/blog/2018/12/survey-raking-an-illustration/).

Essentially this method requires that you only know the **marginal totals** of the sample and the population (usually from a census or some other official statistic).  You do not need to have the cross-classified totals.  In fact, it would be very difficult to work with small samples and cross-classified totals due to the [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality).

If you don't have marginal totals, there's very little you can do without assuming some sort of model for your data and further estimation, which really isn't ideal.